# Arduino User Input

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-ide

Is it possible to accept input from an end user via terminal, or some other application?

I want to create a prototype for a friend, but he'd need to enter his wireless network and password to complete the setup of the project.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Use [Serial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/serial). It can be used to send text to the console, and receive text-input from the user.

Comment: Is there a way to use the c prompt? I hate to have him download something and hung up on the install. I realize it's simple but he's not computer savvy. Thanks for the info!

Comment: No, you can't do it from the "c prompt". You need some kind of serial terminal. Many versions of Windows come with *Hyper Terminal* which will do the job.  Downloading a terminal program isn't a onerous task or particularly difficult. There are many to choose from and they are easy to install.  I have never known one to get "hung up on the install".

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned that all that you want your friend to do is enter the WiFi SSID and password, I am gonna assume that its where his interaction with the device ends.

In this case, I would recommend using the arduino YUN, it cant get simpler than that.

The YUN is capable of creating an AP network, your friend can connect to it and then go to the arduino home page and then connect to his WiFi.

**EDIT:**

Another option would be to use a matrix keypad and LCD screen and have your friend manually enter the details

Comment: Ya, I see that recommendation, thought of it, but don't think 80 bucks is worth the project to buy the yun.

Comment: you could always use a matrix keypad and a LCD display for entering the details.

Via the computer will involve installing drivers and will require you to create a simple app to send data via the serial port

Comment: Yes, I think that's going to be the best answer. Thanks :)